# After updating to newer version of Xcode (14.3 version) TextField shouldChangeCharactersIn method is breaking

Tags: ios, swift, xcode14

> textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range:
> NSRange, replacementString string: String)

We are using this method to limit the character count and we have seen after updating to latest version this method is returning wrong value.

Example :-

This method is getting called twice.

```
    let currentText = textField.text ?? ""

    // attempt to read the range they are trying to change, or exit if we can't
    guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else { return false }

    // add their new text to the existing text
    let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)

    // make sure the result is under 10 characters
    return updatedText.count <= 10
```

This method is getting called twice and replacement string is coming "" like this.
This was working as expected earlier.

Comment: I can confirm this as a problem. We are using it for format the text using a mask like 000-000. Noticed today that we do not get the string to be replaced any more with xcode 14.3

Comment: Can also confirm having the exact same issue with Xcode 14.3.

Comment: Yes I am still facing this issue.

Comment: Anybody found the solution for this